# Can threads from different processes have the same id?

Tags: c++, multithreading, process

I am coding a program in which I want to create several processes and several threads for each of these processes. In short, my program creates several processes and several threads per process.

This is a brief snippet of the code:

```
void NormalityComponent::newThread(int thread_id){
    std::cout << "New Thread [" << thread_id +1 << "] created in Component [" << name_component << "] with id " << std::this_thread::get_id() << std::endl;
    timeSimulation();
    std::cout << "Thread [" << thread_id +1 << "] in [" << name_component << "] with id " << std::this_thread::get_id() << " ends its simulation" << std::endl;
}

void NormalityComponent::timeSimulation(){
    for (int i = 0; i < time_factor * TEMPORAL_PARAMETER; i++);    
}

void NormalityComponent::startAnalysisMode3(){
    //creation of a new process to simulate the Normality Component Analysis and a thread for each Instance.

            pid_t pid = fork();
            if (pid == 0){
                  //Child Process
                  std::cout << "New Normality Component ["<< name_component <<"] created with id " << getpid() << std::endl;
                  //Creation of instances
                    for(int i = 0; i < number_instances;i++){
                        v_threads.push_back(std::thread(&NormalityComponent::newThread,this, i));
                        std::this_thread::sleep_for (std::chrono::milliseconds(100));
                    }

                    std::for_each(v_threads.begin(), v_threads.end(), std::mem_fn(&std::thread::join));

                    kill(getpid(), SIGTERM); //it ends the process when the threads finish. 
            }
}
```

and this is a fragment of the output:

```
New Thread [1] created in Component [Velocity] with id 140236340983552
New Thread [1] created in Component [FaceRecognition] with id 140236340983552
New Thread [1] created in Component [Trajectories] with id 140236340983552
New Thread [2] created in Component [Velocity] with id 140236332590848
New Thread [2] created in Component [Trajectories] with id 140236332590848
New Thread [2] created in Component [FaceRecognition] with id 140236332590848
```

Can threads from different processes have the same id?. It's strange, the identifier of each thread should be unique, right?.

Comment: Sure they can have the same id within different processes, why would you assume they can't? _"It's strange, the identifier of each thread should be unique, right?"_ No, that assumption is wrong, where did you get it from?

Comment: unique in a single process memory space, I don't see why you could be sure of this unicity in other context.

Comment: How would different programs know the IDs of threads created in each other, which they would need in order to be unique?

Comment: I know that each process has reserved its space in memory and that the threads of a process share that space. But I am especially struck by the fact that the first threads of each process have the same identifier. The same is true for those who are created in second and third order.  Perhaps this could happen with processes that come from the same father.

Answer (score 0):

These thread ids look more like addresses. The value returned by `this_thread::get_id()` is not necessary the same as system "thread id". It mostly serves the purpose of providing string comparison / work as key for threads in associative containers. You may want to try calling `gettid` or [`GetCurrentThreadId`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/processthreadsapi/nf-processthreadsapi-getcurrentthreadid). Note that on windows *"Until the thread terminates, the thread identifier uniquely identifies the thread throughout the system."* so threads from different processes can not have the same id. On other platforms behavior may be different.

Comment: What you're saying about the system identifying each thread univocally sounds more logical to me. I'm running the code in gnu/linux. Anyway I'm going to try what you propose. Thank you ;)

Answer (score 0):

> You may want to try calling gettid or GetCurrentThreadId

@VTT, gettid() worked for me.

```
void NormalityComponent::newThread(int thread_id){
pid_t tid = (pid_t) syscall (SYS_gettid);

std::cout << "New Thread [" << thread_id +1 << "] created in Component [" << name_component << "] with id " << tid << std::endl;
timeSimulation();
std::cout << "Thread [" << thread_id +1 << "] in [" << name_component << "] with id " << tid << " ends its simulation" << std::endl;
```

}

This solution provides an unique identifier for each thread. An example of output is as follows:

```
New Normality Component [Trajectories] created with id 5118
New Normality Component [Velocity] created with id 5119
New Thread [1] created in Component [Trajectories] with id 5121
New Normality Component [FaceRecognition] created with id 5120
New Thread [1] created in Component [Velocity] with id 5122
New Thread [1] created in Component [FaceRecognition] with id 5123
New Thread [2] created in Component [Trajectories] with id 5124
New Thread [2] created in Component [Velocity] with id 5125
New Thread [2] created in Component [FaceRecognition] with id 5126
Thread [1] in [Velocity] with id 5122 ends its simulation
New Thread [3] created in Component [Trajectories] with id 5127
New Thread [3] created in Component [FaceRecognition] with id 5128
New Thread [4] created in Component [FaceRecognition] with id 5129
```

Anyway, I would like to understand why this_thread::get_id() does not return the thread id. If you look at the c++ documentation you will see how the function description indicates that it returns the thread identifier.

Comment: *I would like to understand why `this_thread::get_id()` does not return the thread id.*  It does return the thread id.  `gettid()` is a Linux-specific function that returns something else entirely - the *process id* of the *thread* that called it.  Linux - along with many other operating systems - does not have a clean differentiation between threads and processes.  Linux threads could be described as "different processes that share the same address space".

Answer (score 0):

The [linux man page for fork](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/fork.2.html) specifically mentions the thread in the forked process will have the same thread id as the forkee's process thread:

> - The child process is created with a single thread—the one that
>   called fork().

So yes, multiple processes' threads can (and often do) have the same thread id.